# In C# WinForms, MouseMove event on UserControl give 2 different values every other iteration

Tags: c#, winforms

The code for custom control and its implementation is shown below,

`data.txt` shows two completely different values printed for `X` and `Y` every other iteration.

The control is created in `MainForm.cs`

What is causing this problem and how can it be resolved?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Joystick joystick = new Joystick();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        joystick.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 325);
        joystick.Name = "alJoystick";
        joystick.TabIndex = 3;
    }
...


public partial class Joystick : UserControl
{
    public Joystick()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Joy_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("data.txt", "X:" + e.X.ToString() + " Y:" + e.Y.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Data.txt

```
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
X:11 Y:17
X:37 Y:40
```

Joystick visibly jumps around as shown below

[image]